# Create String.Format like string and extract sub string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

First of all, I want extract sub-string from string between delimiters into parameters and make the string become like a string for String.Format.

**Example**

Source:

```
<Hello> [World]!
```

Output:

Result string

```
<{0}> [{1}]!
```

Extracted parameters in array

```
0: Hello
1: World
```

There are lots of strings which contains an unknown amount of parameter. Also, there are two types of delimiter: `<>` and `[]`.

I searched for string extraction example using regex but most of them are base on a static string format. However, the format of string is unknown and may or may not be contain any delimiters in this case.

Edit:
There is a possibility delimiter wrap by other delimiters but delimiter will always come in pair.

**Example**

Source:

```
[<Hello> World]!
```

Output:

Result string

```
[{0}]!
```

Extracted parameters in array

```
0: <Hello> World
```

Only outer delimiter will be considered. Anything inside should be parameters.

Comment: So basically a reference engineer of a `String.Format`?

Comment: You may consider using `string.Split` combined with taking off the last of char: `World] -> World`. `string.Split` may take multiple delimiters after all.

Comment: @AustinWBryan Kind of. I need to store them separately.

Comment: @lan I do not know which one is parameter and result when using String.Split.

Comment: Can my string look like "[he>>o]"?

Comment: @Mathemats No, but it is possible that `[<Hello>]` (or any wrapping delimiter). Then result string should be `[{0}]` and parameter should be `<Hello>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using a Regex to parse out matching sets of `<>` and `[]`. Then you use a [regex replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx) with a [custom MatchEvaluator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator(v=vs.110).aspx)

Something like this might work:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\<).*(?=\>)|(?<=\[).*(?=\])");
var input = "<Hello> [World]!";
var index = 0;
var replacements = new List<string>();
var formatString = regex.Replace(input, (m) => 
{
    replacements.Add(m.Value);
    return String.Format("{{{0}}}", index++);
});
```

I haven't really dealt with input strings that contain `<>[]` but you could make up and escaping pattern and deal with it. The original regex was based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/546456/33969).

*Edit:* [Here's a .NET Fiddle for it...](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YFnStc)

Comment: I did a simple test and works as expected, thank you! =)

Comment: Just a remark. I use `@"(?<=\<).*?(?=\>)|(?<=\[).*?(?=\])"` instead of `@"(?<=\<).*(?=\>)|(?<=\[).*(?=\])"` because original one is greedy. `[Hello] [World]` will be become `[{0}]`. Add `?` will make it lazy and result in `[{0}] [{1}]`.